# How can I calculate the age using todays date and date of birth in php

Tags: php, html, forms, date, datetimepicker

//Html code

```
<div class="form-group">
<input name="dateOfBirth" type="date" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Date of birth is required">
</div>
```

// php code

```
$todaysDateSpecific = date("Y-m-d");
$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];
$customerAge = date_diff(date_create($todaysDateSpecific, date_create($dateOfBirth)));
```

// The customerAge is not calculated
// It desplays error message

> Warning: date_diff() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Beer sales and //distribution management system\company_customer_management.php on line 94

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in

```
$customerAge = date_diff(date_create($todaysDateSpecific, date_create($dateOfBirth)));
```

You have `date_create`, which returns a DateTime object from a parameter. In your case, you are passing both dates as parameters in one `date_create`.

Try:

```
$todaysDateSpecific = date_create("2017-03-15");
$dateOfBirth = date_create($_POST['dateOfBirth']);
$customerAge = date_diff($todaysDateSpecific, $dateOfBirth);
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the age, get the years between today and DOB:

Assuming the POST['dateOfBirth'] is with format "YYYY-mm-dd"

```
<?php


$today = date("Y-m-d"); 

$dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth']; 

// $dateOfBirth = '1987-10-14'; 


$xtoday =strtotime($today);

$xdateOfBirth =strtotime($dateOfBirth);

$diff = abs($xdateOfBirth - $xtoday); 

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));

echo $years; 

?>
```